# How should I structure my data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a social media app and currently, I am storing Usernames, Users, and Posts in Firestore. I am afraid that it will be expensive if there are lots of users(around 50,000). So I planned to store half of the data in Firestore and other half in Realtime Database. Now I am confused if should store the Posts or the Users in Realtime Database. In which database should I put the Posts (Realtime or Firestore)?

Comment: You can split it up all you want, but 50,000 users is still 50,000 users. I would think it would be preferable to have a single data source.

Comment: You're asking for a product recommendation, so your question is likely to get closed. That said, if you think RTDB will be cheaper and that is your reason for moving, why not move to RTDB entirely? And once you answer that, that should help you determine which data to put into which database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Which database will be faster? RTDB or Firestore

Comment: "faster" for what? If one of them was pertinently faster (or better in another way), why would we have the other? The [database recommender](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore#which_database_does_firebase_recommend) in the documentation gives the best guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to stick with 1 source of truth.  Between the two I would choose firestore.

There is a pretty good comparison between the two and their tradeoffs here.  Do you care only about mobile or do you want your app to work on web and mobile?  I'd go with firestore if that is the case.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Also you mention you have Usernames, Users, and Posts in your database.  You should be storing usernames in your "Users" collection so you would really only have two different collections for these "Users" and "Posts".  Also between the two, you are likely going to have more posts than there are users.

Comment: Wont it make it more expensive if I have all data in one place?? Is it ok to keep the users in RTDB and posts in Firestore or is there a drawback to it? Also I created a usernames collection so people cant have same usernames.

Comment: It is generally not good to store your data in multiple places.  You need to consider multiple things.

Are you going to spend the time to maintain/update infrastructure to support data and not have duplication among the two sources just to save a little bit of cost?  What about when your number of users exceeds free tier for both databases?  Are you going to start using AWS as well?

Ideally if you ever hit user count of 50,000+ like you mention above, you would have some way to monetize a little bit to help pay for costs.  You need to also consider your time.